# Change the input values with respect to select option in each row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**Demo**  http://phppot.com/demo/jquery-dependent-dropdown-list-countries-and-states/

Consider country and state are in single row like..

[image]

I populated the row dynamically using javascript. How can I achieve the same functionality in each row as in the first row? If you could resolve this it would be real favour for me.

Comment: can you provide what you have tried?

Comment: Please visit the link that I shared while arising the question. Entire codes of html, ajax and php has been depicted there. Please check it out...

Comment: @KiranKumar The link doesn't show us what you've tried so far... Maybe you should consider reading this (again) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
We are here to help each other, therefor we need to see the problem (code etc.)

Comment: @KiranKumar Please try .clone() method of jquery. Here's the link :http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_clone.asp

Comment: The following link has the codes that I used,

Comment: http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-dependent-dropdown-list-countries-and-states/

Answer (score 0):

Pass the element instead of value to the function `getState()` on change of `country-list` like below.

```
<select onchange="getState(this);" class="demoInputBox" id="country-list" name="country">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="1">Brazil</option>
    <option value="2">China</option>
    <option value="3">France</option>
    <option value="4">India</option>
    <option value="5">USA</option>
</select>
```

And change the `getState()` function like below. Assume your the [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) element of each row is `tr` (use whatever your closest element is).

```
function getState(elm) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_state.php",
        data:'country_id='+elm.value,
        success: function(data){
            //assume `tr` is closest element of each row
            $(elm).closest('tr').find('.state-list').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```